# Can use of multiple naming conventions be consistent?

Tags: python, naming-conventions, python-3.5

I've been taught that while both *camelCase* and *under_scores* are acceptable variable names I need to be consistent in my approach.

How consistent is consistent though? Is it acceptable and Pythonic to use both under certain circumstances?

E.g. could I use *camelCase* for variables in my main code and *under_scores* for those in my functions? or perhaps one for variables which have answers derived from my own functions and one for other functions?

Both of these could be done in a way that makes it easy for those reading it to understand and follow basic systematical rules does that alone make it okay to use both or am I expected to follow through with only one naming convention?

Example of using *under_scores* for variables whose answer is derived from a user defined function and *camelCase* for other variales.

```
# My function.
def reverse(variableCalledA):
    variableNamedB = reverseVariableA(variableCalledA)  # {= 235}.
    return variableNamedB

# Main code.
variableCalledA = 532
**reversed_variable_called_b** = reverse(variableCalledA)
answer = variableCalledA - **reversed_variable_called_b**
print(answer)
```

P.S. If this is appropriate than is it something I should mention in a comment so other users know to look out for it?

P.S.S. Please alert me to any ways I could update/improve my question and future questions.

Comment: For any coding, you should be consistent with the rest of the code in the module/project.  For new modules/projects in python, you should follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) which never supports `camelCase` and advises `CapWords` for classes, `UPPER_CASE` for constants and `names_with_underscores` for everything else.

Comment: Totally opinion based so off topic. Although every one should agree that you should be as consistent as possible, and there is usually no real obstacle to being completely consistent with PEP8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naming conventions are there to increase code clarity and make it easier for many developers to work on the same code base.

As such, the answer to your question really depends on the situation. If you are working in a professional setting you should adhere to whatever naming convention the company uses. If there is no existing naming convention, you should push for one. Generally, any new Python project should adhere to the [PEP8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), unless there's a good reason not to (for example: years of legacy code that uses a different style guide).

No matter if you are working on a new project or on legacy code, my personal opinion is that mixing camelCase and under_scores is just not a good idea. The example you provided sounds reasonable, but it is not a convention that other developers would know about unless it was explained in comments.

Answer (score 0):

For being consistent you can use *under_scores* instead of *camelCase* as the former is more readable than the latter. You can see one of the posts on naming-convention [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/27293).

*Is it acceptable and Pythonic to use both under certain circumstances?*

Yes it is acceptable and pythonic to use both but under only certain circumstances. You can check [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guid for devs.

For function names

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.

Certain circumstances include backward compatibility

> mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the prevailing style (e.g. threading.py), to retain backwards compatibility.

For Class names

> Class names should normally use the CapWords convention.
>
> The naming convention for functions may be used instead in cases where the interface is documented and used primarily as a callable.

Concluding, if you are building on top of some library it is better to go with the library style. For pythonic conventions [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is there to guide devs.

Answer (score 0):

Is the code for yourself or a project you are working on with others?  I think it is best to follow the style standards of the team.  This way your team can follow your code.

When you write for yourself.  Use the system that makes sense to you so that when you are reading the code a year from now you don't have to struggle.

PEP8 makes sense.   CapWords for classes, UPPER_CASE for constants and names_with_underscores for everything else.

I put excessive comments in my code.  Even with variables fully spelled out comments still help.

For people like me with CRS (Can't Remember Shit)  long variable names help me remember what the variable holds, when I go back and look at the code.